# Hovering via CSS in Chrome + GWT

Tags: css, google-app-engine, gwt, google-chrome, webkit

I have a weird Chrome problem. I'm using the following code and style to show `<div class="hoverslave">` on hovering:

```
<div class="hoverhome">
    <div class="...">...</div>
    <div class="hoverslave">...</div>
</div>
```

.

```
.hoverhome:hover .hoverslave {
    display: inline;
}

.hoverhome .hoverslave {
    display: none;
}

.editelement {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

It works only in this configuration. If I comment out or even delete the `.editelement` block (a class "editelement" doesn't even exist in the DOM...) `.hoverslave` will be shown all the time:

```
/*.editelement {
    *display: inline-block;*
    margin-left: 10px;
}*/
```

Same if I try to add the `margin-left: 10px;` anywhere else (`div`, `.hoverslave`, ...). How can I get a margin of 10 px on the left side of `.hoverslave`?

Everything also works as expected when I run the application locally, but not when it's deployed on Google App Engine. The W3C CSS Validator doesn't show any errors.

Comment: Workaround: `position: relative; left: 10px;` on `.hoverslave`?

Comment: I'll try that. But I think I found the reason: I'm using GWT's SafeHtmlBuilder in a wrong way. I'll post an update after fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the bug: I was using GWT's `SafeHtmlBuilder` in the wrong way. The opening and closing tags were not inside one SafeHtml object.

**Wrong:**

```
sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div class=\"hoverhome\">");
sb.appendHtmlConstant("...");
sb.appendHtmlConstant("</div>");
```

The correct way is explained on the [GWT website](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml.html#Creating_SafeHtml_Values). My solution now uses Templates:

```
sb.append(TEMPLATE.hoverhome(title, actions));
```

I also made the mistake to load the CSS file via a  tag in the host HTML page. This method is now deprecated. Using inline  elements everything is working. More details on the [GWT page.](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html#cssfiles)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the margin to the CSS declaration which shows `.hoverslave`.

[Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/VLYUa/1/)

Comment: That breaks the hovering effect.

Comment: I know. That's why I call it a weird problem. It's also working on my computer, but not when I deploy it. The reason is probably my wrong usage of GWT's SafeHtmlBuilder. I'm trying to fix it now.